# How do I get rid of the frameboard surrounding the <details> & <summary> tags?

Tags: html, css, html-tag-details, html-tag-summary

If you click on the  or  a grey-blue frameboard appears surrounding the title.
How do I edit CSS & HTML?

```
<style>
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
    display:none;
    color:transparent;
</style>
```

Visit https://jimmydance.com/belly-dance-history.html and have a look.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use :

```
summary {
    outline: none;
}
```

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/Paf_Sebastien/vdxft2o3/